# How different Rindler wedges are placed on the AdS$_2$ spacetime via $SL(2)$ isometries?

Tags: symmetry, resource-recommendations, ads-cft

I am currently reading the paper https://arxiv.org/abs/1606.01857. In it they state that there are different choices for placing different Rindler wedges on the AdS$_2$ Poincaré patch via $SL(2)$ isometries. I am trying to understand this better. Is there a reference that expands more on this? or how could one explicitly check this?